# clion debugger "unable to find and load segment"

Tags: debugging, clion

Am a Jetbrains Intellij fan and just downloaded CLion 2019.2 on Mac OS 10.15.1.

Current variables not loading like they do in Intellij in the debugger window though breakpoints are working. Getting the following error in the LLDB window. Does anyone know a fix?

```
warning: unable to find and load segment named '__OBJC_RO' at 0x7fff7c026000 in '/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib' in macosx dynamic loader plug-in.
warning: unable to find and load segment named '__OBJC_RW' at 0x7fff9c524080 in '/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib' in macosx dynamic loader plug-in.
```